# Check conditions in a group_by to extract a list of items

Tags: r

I have to confirm which  clients ordered in time and paid their products in a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(client=c("Lucas","Muriel","Lucas","Muriel","Jack"),
               order=c("not received","not received","received","received","received"),
               payment=c("received"," received","received","received","received"),
               month=c("May","May","May","Aug","Aug"))
```

I need to do a list of those clients that completed the two steps that my company demand in the same month: to

1. have in the same row  "not received" and "received", like Lucas did in the first row.
2. And to have in a different one "received" and "received", like Lucas did in the third row.

This has to de donde in the same month. That is why tho Muriel did complete both steps, she is not a good client, becouse she did it in tho different months: May and Aug.

And Jack doesnt have the first step, so he is also not included into the "good client list". In this case, Lucas would be the only one that completed our procedures .

I need to have a list of those clients that did complete the procedures.
I was thinking about grouping the clients with group_by by "client" and "month", and then to check if i have the two rows that i need.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `filter` clients which have both the conditions satisfied.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(client, month) %>%
  summarise(val = any(order == 'not received' & payment == 'received') && 
                  any(order == 'received' & payment == 'received')) %>%
  filter(val) %>%
  distinct(client)  -> good_clients

good_clients
#  client
#  <chr> 
#1 Lucas
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, just curious if there is any reason you used the right assign at the end instead of left at the beginning?

Comment: No specific reason here. I usually use left assignment operator.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, thank you so much for your comment. It does solve the problem i posted, but I've just realized I did not showed it right. I completed it: I need to confirm that each clint completed the two steps in the same month. There is any way I can add that to your solution? I tried group_by(month), but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     unite(new, order, payment) %>% 
     group_by(client, month) %>%
     filter(all(c('not received_received', 'received_received') %in% new)) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     distinct(client)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  client
#  <chr> 
#1 Lucas
```